# Tokenizing a string with unequal number of spaces between fields

Tags: python, split, tokenize

I am tryint to tokenize entries from a file. However I am not able to use the `line.split("")` option because of unequal number of spaces between files. I am copying a few lines from my file below:

```
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      00:22:7f:a6:9b:69                                 -79"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:b4:49:49                                 -79"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:31:4e:59   tikona 18002090044            -83"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      00:22:7f:26:9b:69   tikona 18002090044            -74"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:34:0d:c9   tikona 18002090044            -82"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:71:4e:59                                 -85"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:34:21:89   tikona 18002090044            -75"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:34:49:49   tikona 18002090044            -77"
"08-09-2010 21:21:46      04:4f:aa:74:0d:c9                                 -85"
"08-09-2010 21:22:47      18 APs were seen
"
```

I need to access the first column (which is a `datetime` object) the second column (`00:22...`) and the last column (`-79` etc.). I have no trouble accessing the first and second columns, but not the last column. When I do a `info=line.spilt("")`, since the third column might or might no entries, I am not able to determine the token number.

How do i access the 4th column? Is there a way i can use `info[i].contains(" -")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rsplit to get the last value, something like "".rsplit(" ",1)

Comment: Thanks very much. I am currentky looping over the line as follows:for i in range(0,len(info)):
                if(info[i].startswith(" -")):
                    mailInd=i;
                end                    
                
        end  Yours looks like an easier solution. Thanks very much

Comment: @gatechgrad Please reconsider using `split()` and `rsplit()`. See my answer for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @marcog. I have modified my code using your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The columns look fixed-width, in which case you can use string slicing followed by a possible `.strip()` to remove trailing whitespace:

```
>>> for line in data.split('\n'):
...     print (line[1:25].strip(), line[26:45].strip(), line[46:69].strip(), line[70:-1].strip())
... 
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '00:22:7f:a6:9b:69', '', '-79')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:b4:49:49', '', '-79')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:31:4e:59', 'tikona 18002090044', '-83')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '00:22:7f:26:9b:69', 'tikona 18002090044', '-74')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:0d:c9', 'tikona 18002090044', '-82')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:71:4e:59', '', '-85')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:21:89', 'tikona 18002090044', '-75')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:49:49', 'tikona 18002090044', '-77')
('08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:74:0d:c9', '', '-85')
('08-09-2010 21:22:47', '18 APs were seen', '', '')
('', '', '', '')
```

The `('', '', '', '')` comes from the final input line being `"`.

If the columns are *not* fixed-width, then you can still use `.split()` and get the *last* column using the index `-1`. Although you should use `.split()` with caution here as it's a bit of a mess when done "right". I recommend using a double-space as the separator to handle the `18 APs were seen` case, but note that this changes the index for the second column.

```
>>> for line in data.split('\n'):
...     fields = line.split('  ')
...     print (fields[0], fields[3], fields[-1])
... 
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '00:22:7f:a6:9b:69', ' -79"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:b4:49:49', ' -79"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:31:4e:59', '-83"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '00:22:7f:26:9b:69', '-74"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:0d:c9', '-82"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:71:4e:59', ' -85"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:21:89', '-75"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:34:49:49', '-77"')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '04:4f:aa:74:0d:c9', ' -85"')
('"08-09-2010 21:22:47', '18 APs were seen', '18 APs were seen')
('"08-09-2010 21:21:46', '00:22:7f:26:9b:69', '-74"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The `IndexError` is due to your last input line. You should catch this error if this is real input.

Comment: This is *the* way to handle fixed length records. You could even add something for the third column so you'd end up with an empty string when it wasn't present.

Comment: @marcog: The OP should **NOT** prefer to use split() for fixed-width-columns data under any circumstances. The second part of your answer is just a horrible kludge; please delete it.

Comment: @John OP hasn't confirmed that the data is in fixed-width columns. If he does, then I fully agree. For now, I've added a warning and made it explicit this should only be used if the columns are not fixed-width.

Comment: You should be able to filter out the non-columns by doing: `fields = (x for x in line.split('  ') if x.strip())`

Comment: @Ryan But we want to keep column 3 as column 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it with a regular expression,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

mac_data_re = re.compile(
    r'^(?P<date>[\d-]+)\s+' +
    r'(?P<time>[\d:]+)\s+' +
    r'(?P<mac>[\da-f:]+)\s+' +
    r'(?P<host>\w+){0,1}\s+' +
    r'(?P<host_id>\d+){0,1}\s+'
    r'(?P<final_number>-{0,1}\d+)$')

with file('list') as f:
    for line in (l.strip() for l in f):
        match = mac_data_re.match(line)
        if match:
            print "date={date}, time={time}, mac={mac}, host={host}, host_id={host_id} final_number={final_number}".format(**match.groupdict())
        else:
            print "Line not matched: '%s'" % line
```

Here's the output,

```
 aid@bullet:~/tmp$ ./parse_list.py 
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=00:22:7f:a6:9b:69, host=None, host_id=None final_number=-79
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:b4:49:49, host=None, host_id=None final_number=-79
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:31:4e:59, host=tikona, host_id=18002090044 final_number=-83
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=00:22:7f:26:9b:69, host=tikona, host_id=18002090044 final_number=-74
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:34:0d:c9, host=tikona, host_id=18002090044 final_number=-82
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:71:4e:59, host=None, host_id=None final_number=-85
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:34:21:89, host=tikona, host_id=18002090044 final_number=-75
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:34:49:49, host=tikona, host_id=18002090044 final_number=-77
date=08-09-2010, time=21:21:46, mac=04:4f:aa:74:0d:c9, host=None, host_id=None final_number=-85
Line not matched: '08-09-2010 21:22:47      18 APs were seen'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the code that writes that file? If so you can change it to use tab delimited fields, then split on the tabs. That will maintain consistent field separation.

Comment: No I dont, but looks like it is working now. Thanks so much for your help.